# How to create a single webdriver instance in python so that i can access it everywhere in my code?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest

*I am trying to create a framework for selenium but stuck with this driver initialization.PLz help*

**This is the Base.py file which will execute for the first time.(Here i have written function to lunch the Browser)**

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    import configparser
    from Utility import Read_Properties

global driver
    class Base:

        def Lunch_Browser(name):
            if name == 'chrome':
                driver = webdriver.Chrome(
                    executable_path='C:/Users/MANJKUM/PycharmProjects/Paintshop/Driver/chromedriver.exe')
                driver.implicitly_wait(50)
                driver.maximize_window()
                driver.get(Read_Properties.readproperty('LOGINDETAIL', 'URL'))
                return driver

            elif (name == 'ff'):
                driver = webdriver.firefox(
                    executable_path='C:/Users/MANJKUM/PycharmProjects/Paintshop/Driver/chromedriver.exe')
                driver.implicitly_wait(50)
                driver.maximize_window()
                `enter code here`driver.get(Read_Properties.readproperty('LOGINDETAIL', 'URL'))
                return driver
                else:
                print('No Browser')
```

**Here I have written code for the ID & xpath of all the web element for the loginpage.**
its like page object model.
**Login.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from Utility import Read_Properties
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from Base import Base
class login(object):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.username = driver.find_element(By.ID,'username')
        self.password = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password')
        self.login_tbtn = driver.find_element('login-loginbutton')
    def username(self):
        return self.username
    def password(self):
        self.password.clear()
        self.password.send_keys(Read_Properties.readproperty('LOGINDETAIL', 'PASSWORD'))
    def login_btn(self):
        return self.login_tbtn
```

**Below code is for test_login.py**
Here I want to write the test case for the loginpage.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from Base import Base
from POM_Project.Pages.Login import login
from Utility import Read_Properties
from POM_Project.Pages import Login
from Utility import Read_Properties

driver = webdriver.chrome
#obj_Base=Base()
obj_login=login(driver)

def test_Login():
    Base.Base.Lunch_Browser('chrome')
    time.sleep(20)
    obj_login.username(driver)
    obj_login.password(driver)

test_Login()
```

Comment: You can write a session-scoped fixture that creates and returns the driver and use it in the test via passing its name in the args list.

Comment: @hoefling I have tried with  fixture but the one problem is , I am able to access it in all the test class.  but don't know how to access it in the Pageobject (Login.py>> login class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pytest framework. Its very easy to implement your scenario with fixture.

You can create browser class and then assign driver to self._ in that class constructor.
you can use browser class as a base class, wherever you need web-driver instance.